# Is this a multi-threading race condition problem?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pyserial

In a python3 tkinter project, I am trying to read a continuous stream of data from a serial port (just an arduino sending a milli second value over USB).

The code which reads serial data runs in a separate thread so as to disconnect it from the GUI loop.

I need to be able to connect and disconnect from the serial port, which is done from the GUI.

Everything works up until I disconnect from the serial port when I get the following error.

I was expecting that once, the serialConnect.close() function is called in the main code, the serialStream function would just run 'pass' (line 14) until the connection is opened again -- the error suggests it is still running line 12.

Is this a race condition error, I wonder and how to fix it?

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (serialStream):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/soon/Python/mwe_threaded_serial.py", line 12, in serialStream
    rawReading = str(serialConnection.readline())
  File "/home/soon/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 575, in read
    buf = os.read(self.fd, size - len(read))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

This is from a minimal working example, which looks like this:

```py
import serial
import threading
import time

# Change to correct serial port on your system
serialPort = "/dev/ttyACM0"
serialConnection = serial.Serial()

def serialStream():
    while True:
        if (serialConnection.is_open):
            rawReading = str(serialConnection.readline())
            print(rawReading)
        else:
            pass


def connect_serial():
    global serialConnection, serialPort
    
    # In case serial connection is already oåpen
    if (serialConnection.is_open):
        serialConnection.close()
        time.sleep(1)

    serialConnection = serial.Serial(
            port=serialPort,\
            baudrate=9600,\
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
            timeout=1)
    time.sleep(1)

    if (not serialConnection.is_open):
        print("Connection failed")
    else:
        print("Connection establied")

thread = threading.Thread(target=serialStream)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

connect_serial()

time.sleep(5)
serialConnection.close()
time.sleep(5)
connect_serial()
```

If anyone needs an example arduino code to send a milli reading:

```c
void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication at 9600 bits per second:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(millis());
  delay(1);  // delay in between reads for stability
}
```

Comment: You're accessing a shared resource from multiple threads with no synchronization. It would be a miracle if you didn't have race conditions.

Comment: Yes: between checking `serialConnection.is_open` and calling `serialConnection.readline()`, the connection gets closed.

Comment: This is not trivial. I've tried fixing the issue with lock in appropriate places - no luck thus far. But I'll post the solution here, when I get it right.